# Table is not refreshing after delete in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I did delete operation in mvc 4 using jquery. If i click delete button I just set Isactive =0 for particular column.

**Jquery**

```
 $('.btnDelete').live("click", function () {

            var didconfirm = confirm("Are you sure ?");
            debugger;
            if (didconfirm == true)
            {
                var emaildata = $(this).closest('td').siblings(':first-child').text();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Home/delete",
                    contentType: "application/json; chatset=utf-8",                    
                    //data: "{ 'EmailId' : '" + $(this).attr("data-member") + "'}",
                    data: "{ 'EmailId' : '" + emaildata + "'}",
                    confirm: "Need to delete this",
                    onSuccess: "deleteConfirmation",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Record deleted Successfully");                        

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**Action Code**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult delete(string EmailId)
        {
            var linq = (from db in userobject.UserTables
                        where EmailId==db.EmailId
                        select db).FirstOrDefault();
            if (linq.EmailId == EmailId)
            {
                linq.IsActive = false;
                UpdateModel(linq);
                userobject.SaveChanges();


            }

            return RedirectToAction("Home");
        }
```

This opeartion working fine but my page shows same record while i click some other functions.How to Remove the deleted records when i click the delete function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery live is depreciated function in latest jquery

Comment: @JobinJose what if he is not using latest version then?

Answer (score 0):

In your success function remove the deleted tr from the table (assuming you have a delete button in each table row):

```
     $('.btnDelete').live("click", function () {

        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        ...

        $.ajax({
        ...
            success: function (data) {
                       $tr.remove();

                       alert("Record deleted Successfully");                        

      }
```

Comment: @dinesh.k are your delete buttons inside each row? (inside td's, basically)

Comment: this is my jquery code:-                                                                items += "<tr><td >" + count.EmailId + "</td><td>" + count.FirstName + "</td><td>" + count.UsertTypeName + "</td><td>" + '<input type="button" class="btnEdit" value="Edit" data-member='+ count.EmailId +' />' + "</td><td>" + '<input type="button" Value="Delete" class="btnDelete" id="btnDeleteid" data-member='+count.EmailId+'>' + "</td></tr>";

Answer (score 0):

try this,

you have to create a dynamic id for your table rows, then simply.

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Home/delete",
                    contentType: "application/json; chatset=utf-8",                    
                    //data: "{ 'EmailId' : '" + $(this).attr("data-member") + "'}",
                    data: "{ 'EmailId' : '" + emaildata + "'}",
                    confirm: "Need to delete this",
                    onSuccess: "deleteConfirmation",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //when removed from DB.
                      $("#dynamic_row_id").remove();                     

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the parent tr from the $(this) object( I assume your button is in a td element) and then remove it after successful call back.

```
$('.btnDelete').live("click", function () {

            var didconfirm = confirm("Are you sure ?");
            debugger;
            if (didconfirm == true)
            {
                var emaildata = $(this).closest('td').siblings(':first-child').text();
                var curRow = $(this).parent('tr');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Home/delete",
                    contentType: "application/json; chatset=utf-8",                    
                    //data: "{ 'EmailId' : '" + $(this).attr("data-member") + "'}",
                    data: "{ 'EmailId' : '" + emaildata + "'}",
                    confirm: "Need to delete this",
                    onSuccess: "deleteConfirmation",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Record deleted Successfully");                        
                         curRow.remove();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```